# Using multiple AJAX calls on the same element Bootsfaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, bootsfaces

Can I do something like this:

```
<b:navLink  ...    onclick="ajax:callBeanMethodA;ajax:callBeanMethodB" />
```

Like that doesn't work, is there any way to make it work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I guess your best bet it to combine these two or multiple method calls in a convenience method in your backing bean.**

This way you can also make sure, that they're called in a consistent order:

```
public void combinedMethod() {
    callBeanMethodA();
    callBeanMethodB();
}
```

Then just call the single convenience method from your listener:

```
<b:navLink  ...    onclick="ajax:beanName.combinedMethod" />
```

Other advantages of this approach would be better readability and reusability and maintainability, as you defined the combined logic centrally.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. But on the other hand, it contradicts the goal of orthogonality. I didn't implement it in the current version of BootsFaces, but there's no reason to not implement it. This evening, I'd like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does work. It's just a bit simpler than you thought. Omit the second `ajax:` prefix, and things work fine:

JSF markup:

```
<b:messages id="messages" />
<b:commandButton value="Click me!" 
                 onclick="ajax:menuView.save();menuView.reload()" 
                 update="@form">
</b:commandButton>
```

Java bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MenuView {
  public void save() {
    addMessage("Success", "Data saved");
  }
  public void reload() {
    addMessage("Success", "reloaded");
  }
}
```

[image]